# PHP Laravel eloquent relation not working when using findOrFail

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the profile that relates to the given user on my website.

The relation is setup correctly (I can do this: `Auth::user() -> profile` to access profile data. But when I try to do this: `User::findOrFail(1) -> profile` it gives me an error saying that it's not an object (and the value of profile is equal to `null`. Why is that? And yes the user with the ID of `1` does exist.

In my `User` model I've setup this:

```
public function profile() {
    return $this -> hasOne('App\Profile', 'user_id');
}
```

And in my `Profile` model I've done this:

```
public function user() {
    return $this -> belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

I just saw this problem when grabbing X users and going through them in a foreach loop as seen below.

```
    <div class="thumbs-wrapper text-center">

        @foreach ($last_online as $user)
            <div class="thumb @if(\App\User::isOnline($user -> id)) online @else offline @endif">
                <a href="/profile/view/{{ $user -> id }}">
                    <img src="{{ asset($user -> profile -> picture) }}">
                </a>
            </div>
        @endforeach

    </div>
```

What could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: One or more users in that foreach doesn't have the profile, that's all

Comment: All the users has a profile. It's created upon user registration with the same user_id as the user has. And i have also checked this manually in my database manager.

Comment: Then check the stacktrace and make sure where the error happens.

Comment: Well, it basically says this:

BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2345: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::profile()

Here's a screenshot also: http://i.imgur.com/zPJEaC5.png

So weird I can use `Auth::user() -> profile`...

Comment: It says there's no method `profile` on the `$user` - what's `$user` then?

Comment: I try to do this: `User::findOrFail(1) -> profile`
I also try to do this: `$users = User::with('profile')->take(10)->get();`
Both gives same error. And the $user is a `User` model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121200/discussion-between-kaizokupuffball-and-jarek-tkaczyk).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if I understand your problem correctly

```
User::with('profile')->where('id', '=', 1)->firstOrFail();
```

or if you need load many user with their profiles

```
User::with('profile')->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. And all the users has a profile. It's created upon user registration with the same user_id as the user has.

This gives me this error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::profile()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::profile()
```

profile() exist in user model?

Hmmm...It has to work.

In User model:

```
public function profile() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile', 'user_id');
}
```

In your controller method:

```
$users =  User::with('profile')->get();


dd($users);
```

> Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::profile() Here's a screenshot also:
>   i.imgur.com/zPJEaC5.png So weird I can use Auth::user() -> profile

:)

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
 $user->profile->user_id; //(or whathewer)
}
```